# nil:NilClass error with validation for numericality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Still learning Rails.
This one has me pulling my hair out.

When validating a model, I am trying to make the model valid only for days_in_week of 7 and 14.

I have a simple model:

```
class ScheduleRotum < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :start_date, :end_date, :days_in_week

  validate :trial_trial
  validates :days_in_week, presence: true
  validates :days_in_week, inclusion: { in: [ 7,14 ] } 
  validates :days_in_week, numericality: true


  def initialize(start_date: '', end_date: '', days_in_week: 7)
    @start_date   = start_date
    @end_date     = end_date
    @days_in_week = days_in_week
  end 

  def trial_trial
    unless @days_in_week == 7 or @days_in_week == 14
      errors[:base] << 'Wrong number of dates'
    end 
  end 
end
```

The first three validations work. However any validation including variables for numericality results in an error (in all permutations that I've tried):

```
2) ScheduleRotum#initialize days in week 15 is invalid
   Failure/Error: expect(rotum).not_to be_valid

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

And this is the code for the spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ScheduleRotum, type: :model do
  context 'days in week' do
  it 'is only valid as 7 or 14' do
    rotum = ScheduleRotum.new days_in_week: 14
    expect(rotum).to be_valid
    expect(rotum.days_in_week).to eq 14
  end
  it '15 is invalid' do
    rotum = ScheduleRotum.new days_in_week: 15
    expect(rotum).not_to be_valid
  end

  end
end
```

I cannot figure out why a nilClass is being created with the numericality validation. Any insight?

Comment: I've replicated your workflow. Both examples pass. Do you get some error?

Comment: Your code looks just right except for `errors[:base] <<`, i will write `self.errors[:base] <<`. Do you have any stack trace of the error? What is the role of numericality validation in your error? Are you sure, it is not because of any other validation? Can you try running your tests with only the custom validation `trial_trial` and commenting out all other validations, and see if the error still occurs?

Comment: I only get the error listed above when running rspec. I included the errors[:base] as an example of a passing test. I'm certain it's some kind of configuration issue, and it's good to know that it's passing for you. At least I know I'm not crazy.